Digital Signing of PDF Files with PowerShell
I’ve written a small tool in PowerShell, specifically using PowerShell Studio. It calls a PDF template and populates the form fields based on a CSV file’s content. It then locks the form against changes and saves it. Now, the only missing piece is signing the PDF. In my template, I have a signature field. Ideally, I’d prefer to stick with the iTextsharp library due to licensing reasons. I’ve found numerous examples for both iTextsharp and iText7 libraries, but unfortunately, none specifically address signing with PowerShell.
I am grateful for any Help!
I’ve managed to fill in the fields and lock them using the iTextsharp library, which has plenty of examples available online. However, with the Chilkat library, I’ve successfully signed the PDF, but the locking functionality doesn’t work there. It would be nice if I could either use the signature (name) from the installed certificates or a p12 certificate file, or use the clear name for the signature.
Here is my 1st code (Chillkat) digital signature works perfectly but document is not locked, form fields are freely editable:
Add-Type -Path "$ScriptDirectory\data\lib\ChilkatDotNet48.dll"
    $pdf = New-Object Chilkat.Pdf
    $success = $pdf.LoadFile("$ScriptDirectory\Test_IN.pdf")
    if ($success -eq $false)
    {
        $($pdf.LastErrorText)
        exit
    }
    $json = New-Object Chilkat.JsonObject
    
    $json.UpdateInt("signingCertificateV2", 1)
    $json.UpdateInt("signingTime", 1)
    
    $json.UpdateBool("appearance.fillUnsignedSignatureField", $true)
    $json.UpdateString("unsignedSignatureField", "doctor_signature")
    
    $json.UpdateString("appearance.text[0]", "Digitally signed by: cert_cn")
    $json.UpdateString("appearance.text[1]", "current_dt")
    $json.UpdateString("appearance.text[2]", "The crazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
    
    $json.UpdateString("appearance.image", "green-check-grey-circle")
    $json.UpdateString("appearance.imagePlacement", "left")
    
    $cert = New-Object Chilkat.Cert
    $success = $cert.LoadByCommonName("Test User")
    if ($success -eq $false)
    {
        $($cert.LastErrorText)
        exit
    }
    
    $success = $pdf.SetSigningCert($cert)
    if ($success -eq $false)
    {
        $($pdf.LastErrorText)
        exit
    }
    
    $success = $pdf.SignPdf($json, "$ScriptDirectory\Test_OUT.pdf")
    if ($success -eq $false)
    {
        $($pdf.LastErrorText)
        exit
    }

My 2nd code (iTextSharp) locks the PDF document and works perfectly

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$ScriptDirectory\data\lib\itextsharp.dll")
        
$PdfReader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($PdfFilePath)
$NewPdfFilePath = $PdfFilePath -replace '\.pdf$', '_Sig.pdf'
$PdfStamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($PdfReader, [System.IO.File]::Create($NewPdfFilePath))
        
[iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDate]::new()

$PdfStamper.FormFlattening = $true

$PdfStamper.Close()
$PdfReader.Close()

My 3rd code (iTextSharp) should sign and lock the document but it only creates an empty pdf. I think this code is not correct or incomplete

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$ScriptDirectory\data\lib\itextsharp.dll")
        
$PdfReader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($PdfFilePath)

$NewPdfFilePath = $PdfFilePath -replace '\.pdf$', '_Sig.pdf'
$PdfStamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($PdfReader, [System.IO.File]::Create($NewPdfFilePath))

$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature($SignatureFieldName)
        
$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.SignatureGraphic = $null
$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.Layer2Text = "TestUser"
$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.Reason = "TEXT1"
$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.Location = "TEXT2"
$PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance.SignDate = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDate]::new()
        
$PdfStamper.FormFlattening = $true
        
$PdfStamper.Close()
$PdfReader.Close()
        


Thank you for your message. I prefer the iText libraries but can't find an example for signing at least for Powershell. In general, the documentation for Powershell is very poor for this library. For C# or Java there are these examples in the documentation. I assume that the library has the same functionality everywhere.

I am well aware that Powershell is not the ideal platform for this. However, I don't want to have made my previous program for nothing and porting it to c++ etc. is not done quickly. The Chilkat library has shown me that Powershell is quite capable of signing pdf-files.

Thanks for comment.
When I digitally sign and save a pdf with Adobe Reader or similar, I still have a pdf file. p7s doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I have already signed a pdf with powershell and chilkat file, but the pdf is not locked against changes after signing. Here is the example from Chilkat https://www.example-code.com/powershell/certify_pdf_and_lock_entire_document.asp. With Itextsharp it was easy to lock the pdf file against changes but there I only get errors when signing...

@Guest "With Itextsharp it was easy to lock the pdf file against changes but there I only get errors when signing... " - so you already have PS code for signing with text that merely does not work? You may want to add that code to your question, so we can try to fix it.

For me it is sufficient if the documents are signed and protected against easy editing, e.g. with the adobe reader, I don't need more security. I have inserted my various code snippets in the question and hope someone can help me.

Ah, you "lock" the form by flattening! I assume the problem is here that the signature field also is a form field, so upon closing the stamper the signature field both is being flattened (it's a form field after all) and then attempted to be filled in (for signing). These two changes likely get into each other's way. Consider a two-step approach, first flatten and save the PDF as in your second code, then open that flattened PDF again and sign it as in your first code or third code (without flattening).
